# What is the physical meaning of ghost field and dilaton field in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, ghosts

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.00552) (24)，I found a action of gravity coupling to a free scalar field. According to the literature, the scalar field is ghost or dilaton depending on the sign of kinetic terms. But in this literature the physical meaning of the ghost and dilaton did not be explained. So I  don't know what effect the present of ghost or dilaton can bring.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters in the quoted equation which I will simply to:
$\epsilon_{1} R - \epsilon_{2} (\partial \phi)^2$.

A ghost field is a normal field with the wrong sign of the kinetic term. To get a ghost graviton, you would need to change the sign of the kinetic term of the gravitational action. Their statement is then that if $\epsilon_{1} = -1$, you would get a ghost graviton. Ghost fields are usually used to gauge fix in gauge theory.

The dilaton is a scalar field arising from the dimensional reduction of Einstein gravity in higher dimensions. Here, your reference calls the scalar field the dilaton for this reason, but it is important to note that the action they consider is *not* dilaton gravity. It is simply a minimally coupled scalar field $\phi$ to gravity, with the Einstein-Hilbert term. To turn this scalar into a ghost, you would set $\epsilon_{2} = -1$.

Comment: Does the significance of dilaton field means that if I have a D-dimensional metric in dilaton-Einstein system，I can get a (D+1)-dimensional metric in Einstein system?